# MultiThreading - Closing the form after a function is done

Tags: vb.net

I'm new at 'multithreading' thing, and I need some help for the following code:

Button code:

```
        Dim t As New Thread(AddressOf MThere)
        t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA)
        t.Start()
```

Then...

```
      Sub MThere()

         Try

        MyFunctionHere()
        Me.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub
```

When I run the code, the following is returned:

> Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'Form' accessed from a
>   thread other than the thread it was created on.

How can I close the form after the task has completed? The function I'm using is to send an email so that the form remains responsive.

Comment: First thing to learn about multithreading: Don't. :)

Comment: Please don't ever do `Catch ex As Exception` in your code. Always catch a specific exception that you know you can recover from. Also, an empty `Catch` block is an excellent way for you to create truly buggy code that is almost impossible to fix - avoid empty catch blocks. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some objects, including Windows Forms controls, belong to the thread that created them. If you attempt to access or control them from another thread, you're likely to get exceptions regarding cross-thread operations.

Fortunately, Windows forms have an `Invoke` method that ensures the delegate you pass it will be called on the UI thread, so the error disappears.

So you can do something like this to fix the cross-thread usage problem...

```
Sub MThere()
    Try
        MyFunctionHere()
        Invoke(Sub() Close())
    Catch ex As Exception
        ' this empty catch block is a _really_ bad idea, by the way.
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: gonna try, ty and i removed  the catch ex... field to not to take up too much space :D

Comment: Using Invoke(AddressOf Close) returned me more errors. I used this and worked perfectly: Me.Invoke(Sub() Me.Close)

Comment: @toxdotnet: Yeah, sometimes you can pass an `AddressOf` directly (which is prettier IMO), other times you can't for some reason. I'm not sure about the pattern, and this might be one of those "can't" times. :P